# WPF bindings in window and user control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have Control Library and WPF application. I need to create my custom control to vizualize graph. So I made GraphControl and set there custom attribute GraphData:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty GraphDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GraphData", typeof(Graph), typeof(GraphControl));

public Graph GraphData
{
    get { return (Graph)GetValue(GraphDataProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(GraphDataProperty, value);
        TextBlock.Text = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasd";
    }
}
```

This part is done, but now I want to bind GraphData to property in MainWindow of application where GraphControl is nested. I mean I want to change some graphData property in MainWindow and when I do that, graph rerenders, and all rendering occurs inside control, not window. Ex:

```
<controls:GraphControl x:Name="GraphControl" GraphData="{Binding GraphData}"/>
```

If I create new DependencyProperty in Window, then all changes are handled in window, not control.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, you want to bind a property of your control to a property on the window rather than on the DataContext.
If this is the case, you can achieve it using the RelativeSource attibute, like this:

```
<controls:GraphControl x:Name="GraphControl" GraphData="{Binding Path=GraphData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Comment: + there is no reason to create DependencyProperty in MainWindow class, you should just implement INotifyPropertychanged to bind data to your control.

Comment: @VadimMartynov You see, even with your code when I define new DependencyProperty in Window it becomes new instance and does not affect UserControl. I mean for example I change text inside Control by code in setter in Control code-behind, I put breakpoint there. When my form appears I reach this bp, but not when I set property in Window

Comment: Just to add to Leo's answer you need Mode=TwoWay, to actually make it work. But if you are going to use the same property twice, then don't create it twice, have an attach property instead.

Comment: Well yes actually "Mode=TwoWay" could be the default, depending on the property you're binding.